# Using QML with a qt widgets type of ui form?

Tags: qt, qml

So I would like to create an Application which looks something like this:

[image: click here]

What this application does is, I can select shapes through the combobox on the left and put them on the Area to the right. With the slider I can vary the sizes. The checkboxes select a border or make the shape have a filling color.

My Problem is I would like to create these shapes through using QML, as its relatively easy to create such basic shapes with rectangle, circle etc. ,however I would also like to have the nice interface seen on the left. Is this possible with QML only or do I need to integrate QML into qtwidgets or something like that? I know that there is a slider and a button also present in QML, which look perfectly fine but I would like to have a clear area on the right which indicates to the user where he can create shapes and the ui stuff on the left. What is the correct approach here?

Comment: I don't understand the link between the title of the question and what you want to achieve. You can do everything in QML (and then don't bother with QtDesigner ui at all). Or you can embed some QtQuick in a given QWidget of your window, for example using [`QQuickWidget`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickwidget.html#details) that you can drag&drop in QtDesigner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the drawing part of your app, using `QGraphicsScene` https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsscene.html could also be an alternative to stay with Qt Widget instead of mixing it with QML.

But if you want to stick with QML you can look at `QQuickView` https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickview.html and here is a small example of integration :

```
#include <QQuickView>
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    // ..

    QQuickView *view = new QQuickView;
    QWidget *container = QWidget::createWindowContainer(view, this);

    // some set up if needed
    container->setMinimumSize(1280, 600);
    container->setMaximumSize(1280, 600);
    container->setFocusPolicy(Qt::TabFocus);

    // ..

    view->setSource(QUrl("main.qml"));
    view->setResizeMode(QQuickView::SizeViewToRootObject);

    ui->verticalLayout->addWidget(container);

    // ..

}
```

Comment: Thanks, I found this approach many times on the net and also was able to get some example Project where this approach was used, however I couldn't quite get it to work, and the explanation on how to do this wasn't all too easy to understand for me as I am still relatively new to Qt. But for the time being I will stick to doing everything in QML and perhaps try again in the future.

Comment: Also this approach is not always going to work : for example on embedded Linux when using EGLFS as a QPA backend, you cannot mix OpenGL based windows and Qt Widget windows but if you rely on X11 then it's usually fine.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend using QML for the entire UI.  Firstly, Qt Quick and QWidgets are completely different UI engines. I find markup based UI easier to source control, adjust, and generally work with.  Furthermore, Qt Quick and QML is the best UI framework I've ever used, and there have been many.  You can easily do everything you want.